# How to define a beamer option with theme?

Tags: beamer, themes, class-options

I am trying to create my own beamer theme that should be loaded with beamer's `compress` option by default. I tried using the following declaration, which I saw on a few different answers and themes:

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
```

but the following MWE produces the non-compressed version of the navigation bar, with each `subsection` creating its own line of dots:

[image: nocompress]

```
\begin{filecontents}{beamerthemeCompress.sty}
   \DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
   \ProcessOptionsBeamer

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.25ex]{section in head/foot}
        \tiny\insertnavigation{.2\paperwidth}
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Compress}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Intro Sub1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    Some Text
\end{frame}
\subsection{Intro Sub2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    Some Text
\end{frame}

\section{Cont}
\subsection{Cont Sub1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    Some Text
\end{frame}
\subsection{Cont Sub2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
    Some Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Only when I use `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}` I get the desired compressed version, with all dots on the same line:

[image: yescompress]

How can I make my theme always look like this without having to load the class with `[compress]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `\DeclareOptionBeamer` you just redefine the definition, not execute it. When you then `\ProcessOptionsBeamer` you just execute the options given, not every defined option.

Hence your code effectively does nothing and if you dropped it completely you'd just get the same because the `beamer` class already handles your `compress` option.

Instead, simply execute the option's code as if it was given and you'll get the results you want:

```
\begin{filecontents}{beamerthemeCompress.sty}
   \beamer@compresstrue

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.25ex]{section in head/foot}
        \tiny\insertnavigation{.2\paperwidth}
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Compress}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Intro Sub1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    Some Text
\end{frame}
\subsection{Intro Sub2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    Some Text
\end{frame}

\section{Cont}
\subsection{Cont Sub1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    Some Text
\end{frame}
\subsection{Cont Sub2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
    Some Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```